# Are these reportings/stats typically normal for a CPU?

Tags: windows-10, memory, cpu, bios, motherboard

I was checking my cpu temperatures by using HWiNFO and checking if everything is normal. But i came to notice that the minimum of the Core Clock Speed are "798-797.7 mhz or 0.78-0.79 ghz" but the average is 4.5 ghz and when doing graphs and doing tasks like opening google chrome, and gaming i see it drop to 798 mhz in real-time but only for a solid 2 seconds and comes back normal. It just basically reports that the minimum is 798 mhz/0.78 ghz. the avg for the core clocks are fine 4.7 ghz but im just wondering why in apps such as HWiNFO and HWMONITOR it reports my minimum clock speed from 4.3 ghz before. But now 798 mhz/0.79 ghz but i see it happen in real-time though sometimes. It wont even say in task manager that it dropped to 0.78 ghz only on the two apps i mentioned as minimum clock its either one of the cores are a minimum to 0.79 ghz or some cores but some not. This happens when im using the PC or just using it ingeneral when idling i don't really know.It drops for like a solid 2 seconds.

No prior overclocks including the cpu and gpu were attempted but i did turn on xmp for like 30 mins and reverted the bios settings back to default.

Checking Task Manager nothing's wrong what could be causing this?

Back then it was like 4.3 ghz as minimum but now its 0.78-79 ghz as minimum. Maximum is 4.7 is this worrying? my cpu is not overheating, not thermal throttling or any other than that.

It's not a major issue it's just that it's reported as 0.78-79 ghz as minimum for Core Clock Speed.

If i reset the min and max reports it'll go minimum 4.3 ghz but after some time it turns into 0.79 ghz

Is there anything wrong with my pc? i reverted the bios settings to default just incase. but the saved changes to default werent nearly anything about CPU Clocks, Voltages it was just about TPM and enabling it.

Specs are:

i5 10600

GTX 1050 TI

Intel Stock Cooler

Prime H410M-E

1x8 Kingston Fury RGB No XMP (*But i did turn XMP on before and off and set Memory Frequency to 2666 MHZ but i reverted the settings back to their default option by pressing Default(F5) on EzMode ASUS Bios.

And it does not go stable 0.78-0.79 ghz its just that its reported as the "minimum" core clock speed doesnt go lower than that.

Some Cores for a second go to 798 MHZ/0.79 ghz but it happens fast and immediately goes back to 4.7 or 4.6 ghz this just started happening today and today only i dont remember it happening yesterday.

I was graphing the core clocks and it turns out to be "core 0" and other cores are normal? it's not thermal throttling or anything though.

I dont really know why this is happening this started today. Could this be the XMP or the DRAM Frequency changes that caused this? But i reverted the settings though. The settings are normal now though this might be because of dust. And it's a Intel Stock Cooler of all things.. So i dont know everythings right i reverted the settings no prior CPU OC's by the way. It's only sitting in at stock speed. What could be causing this?

On HWMonitor the only affected cores would be Core 0, Core 2 or Core 3/Any core on HWMonitor i think?

But on HWiNFO its only one core and it's Core 0 that seems to be affected by this.

Should i be worried?

Look at the minimum ghz/mhz value for each photo. The thing is i dont feel any slight delay or stutter or slowdowns when it does do the 0.78 ghz on one core.

https://imgur.com/U6Duz8g

https://imgur.com/0D1Mbsq

https://imgur.com/FuQcMjD

https://imgur.com/iaLp2fd

Comment: The individual core clock speeds will be reduced when possible to reduce power usage. Usually, you would want XMP enabled. There doesn't appear to be a problem to me.

Comment: I mean theres a 65 power limit on my processor so it doesnt go above that.

Comment: this is one of many instances in which digging into data you simply don't understand *always* looks worrying ;)

Comment: I thought i had done something wrong because i applied XMP wasnt really feeling comfortable with enabling the setting and instead reverted the settings back to default.

Comment: So i'd thought to myself i'd done something wrong so i reverted the bios to default three more times but each of them didnt mention any changes done only tpm n etc and then i boot.

Comment: So i tried XMP on this time and turned on pc gamed with it and played with it didnt drop to 798 mhz/0.79 ghz that time so it only happens when i have XMP off which before doing this it was stable and this wouldnt happen to me. So if i have xmp on this doesnt happen and when off it happens right away when i click on chrome.

Comment: This wasnt happening before i did the XMP turning on shit and alla that i even reverted my BIOS to default to make sure and ensure i didnt do anything wrong.

Comment: Every BIOS setting is at default but its still doing it. So i dont know anymore

Comment: Im probably just overreacting but yeah sorry for the hassle guys.